# python - comparing series/dataframe with multi-index dataframe

Tags: python, loops, numpy, pandas

I would like to compare (i.e. > or <) the values in one column of a dataframe, which has a single, non-unique index (`df1`), to the values of another dataframe (`df2`) which has a unique, multi-index. The comparison should be such that the values in `df1` are matched against each value in `df2` with the corresponding index-value of the first level.

E.g. if the value in df1 is smaller than any value in df2 where the first level index matches with the index of the value in df1, the result should display `True'.
An example-code will make this clear

```
index_a = [1,2,2,3,3,3]
index_b = [0,0,1,0,1,2]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([index_a,index_b], names=('a','b'))
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,), index = [1,2,3,3], columns=['p'])    
>>> df1
          p
a          
1  0.672379
2  0.130578
3  0.128918
3  0.346115

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(6,), index=index, columns=['p'])
>>> df2
            p
a b          
1 0  0.187448
2 0  0.596792
  1  0.075301
3 0  0.784842
  1  0.256178
  2  0.691007
```

What I want can be achived as follows:

```
dfexp = df2.unstack('b')
>>> dfexp
          p                    
b         0         1         2
a                              
1  0.187448       NaN       NaN
2  0.596792  0.075301       NaN
3  0.784842  0.256178  0.691007

>>> comp = dfexp.ge(df1.p,axis=0)
>>> comp
       p              
b      0      1      2
a                     
1  False  False  False
2   True  False  False
3   True   True   True
3   True  False   True
>>> comp.any(axis=1)
a
1    False
2     True
3     True
3     True
dtype: bool
```

**Can this be achived without unstacking `df2`?** The problem is, that the second-level labels can be quite large for some of the first-level indices, making the operation very slow and the `expdf` dataframe unnecessarily large. At the same time the index of `df1` can be very large as well, such that I would like to avoid to solve the task by looping over that index unless that loop could be made very, very fast.

Comment: `df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=['p'])` what is `data`?

Comment: How can we create `data` and `index` as used to form `df2`?

Comment: sorry for the missing information. I edited the post.

Comment: please add this `np.random.seed([3,1415])` in a line just above the assignment of `df1`.  This will ensure we are getting the same random numbers.

Answer (score 1):

#### Setup

```
index_a = [1,2,2,3,3,3]
index_b = [0,0,1,0,1,2]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([index_a,index_b], names=('a','b'))
np.random.seed(3)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,), index = [1,2,3,3], columns=['p'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(6,), index=index, columns=['p'])
```

Try:

```
df1.apply(lambda x: (df2.loc[x.name, 'p'] > x.get_value('p')).any(), axis=1)

1     True
2     True
3     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```